# Testing asynchronous Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, jasmine

I am trying to have the function GetUsername to call the actual implementation and return the username if it is found back into the variable result. I am using Jasmine's done function but the test is not correct. It keeps on passing even if the expected and actual value are not the same. Any help or suggestion would be great! Thanks in advance.

Here are my objects:

```js
var Git = {
    VerifyGitUser: function (username, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.github.com/users/' + username
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            callback.call(this, data);
        })
        .fail(function (data) {
            callback.call(this, data);
        })
    }
}

var User = {
    GetUsername: function (username) {
        Git.VerifyGitUser(username, function (data) {
            if (data.login) {
                return data.login;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my test:

```js
describe('User', function () {
    it('should return username', function (done) {
        spyOn(Git, 'VerifyGitUser');

        spyOn(User, 'GetUsername').and.callThrough();

        var result = User.GetUsername('test');
        done();

        expect(Git.VerifyGitUser).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test');
        expect(User.GetUsername).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(result).toEqual('test');
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to retrieve the data from `User.GetUsername` whenever it completes, so it will just return `undefined`. Plus your call to `done()` is completing the test before you assert anything with `expect`.

You can have `User.GetUsername` take a callback, just like you are doing for `Git.VerifyGitUser`:

```
var User = {
    GetUsername: function (username, callback) {
        Git.VerifyGitUser(username, function (data) {
            if (data.login) {
                callback(data.login);
            } else {
                callback(null);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now you know when `User.GetUserName` has completed. So in your test, you can pass `User.GetUserName` a callback which can call `done()`:

```
describe('User', function () {
    it('should return username', function (done) {
        spyOn(Git, 'VerifyGitUser');

        spyOn(User, 'GetUsername').and.callThrough();

        User.GetUsername('test', function(result) {
            expect(Git.VerifyGitUser).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test');
            expect(User.GetUsername).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(result).toEqual('test');

            done();
        });
    })
});
```

Other thoughts:

- Do you need to call the actual API during this test? You can look into returning mock API data from `VerifyGitUser` using Jasmine spies.
- In `VerifyGitUser` I don't see why you need to force context using `callback.call(this, data)`. It seems like `callback(data)` is enough.
- You may want to look into returning promises from async functions, instead of having them take in callbacks.

Comment: No my original unit test is not calling the actual API but I wanted to test it out calling the actual implementation. Good tip on the callback(data). Also, I am getting an error in GetUsername saying that "callback is not a function"

Comment: Did you change the function signature of `GetUserName` to take in a callback, and are you then passing in a callback function as the second parameter when you invoke it?

Comment: oh yeah I just needed to chang ethe function signature of GetUserName